# List all files with extensions .tif, .tiff, .TIF, .TIFF

Tags: bash, find, filenames

Given a nested directory, I would like to list all tif files with extension `.tif`, `.TIF`, `.tiff`, `.TIFF`.

Currently I'm using

```
find . -type f -iname *.TIF -print ; find . -type f -iname *.TIFF -print;
```

Using `-iname` allows me to be case-insensitive but it goes through the directory twice to get files with `.tif` and `.tiff`. Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps with brace expansion?

**Why not `*.tif*`?**

In some cases, my directories might have auxiliary files with extension `.tif.aux.xml` alongside the tiffs. I'd like to ignore those.

Comment: Make an alias with it in your source file for the command, such as "findtif" or something.

Comment: why not do `ren *.tiff *.tif` first ? :-)   (hint: don't)

Comment: @Jeffrey While I don't want to modify the data in question, I'm curious as to why this is discouraged. I mean aside from the fact that it won't fix the auxiliary file problem.

Comment: Do you really need `find`? If you're using `zsh` (which supports recursive `**` in a glob) for instance, `echo **/*.{tif,tiff,TIF,TIFF}` should be enough.

Comment: @vikarjramun The OP's question is marked "bash," although bash does support this. However, this solution does not limit the search results to only include regular files, nor does it allow a lot of the other features that `find` has (which OP may need; not sure).

Comment: @WillEccles Thats why I posted it as a comment, because it technically doesn't answer OP's question, but is still useful information. Anyway, handling `-type f` can be done in zsh with `echo **/*.{tif,tiff,TIF,TIFF}(.)` (zsh glob qualifiers), though I doubt bash has an equivalent.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`find` supports an “or” disjunction, `-o`:

```
find . -type f \( -iname \*.tif -o -iname \*.tiff \)
```

This will list all files whose name matches `*.tif` or `*.tiff`, ignoring case.

`-print` is the default action so it doesn’t need to be specified here. `*`, `(`, and `)` are escaped so that they lose their significance for the shell.

Answer (score 34):

Shorter than using `-o`, use a regular expression instead

```
find . -type f -iregex '.*\.tiff?'
```

Brace expansion is not part of [glob matching](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), so cannot be used with `-(i)name`.

Comment: Explain the regex, please.

Comment: @ScottieH it matches everything ending with `.tif` or `.tiff`

Comment: It is always better to err on the side of caution with these things. The pattern matches `.tif` followed by one or zero `f` characters. `?`makes the previous character optional. Not trying to show off here, just trying to show how small the effort is. noi. :-)

Comment: @ScottieH it matches names ending `.tif` with an optional final `f`

Comment: @Bjorn perfect explanation. Thanks

Comment: This is slower than the `-o` version, by not quite 50% in my tests, although that is probably not significant in most scenarios ;-) — certainly not compared to the I/O time on many systems if the directories aren’t already cached.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple hack to get your desired output assuming you are in the top-level directory of the tree where you want to run the find command. Disclaimer: It will not fit advanced usage or find scenarios:

```
find -type f |egrep '.tif$|.tiff$|.TIF$|.TIFF$'
```

Explanation:

1. By default, gnu find recurses into the current directory and prints the output to stdout (no need of a dot or -print option).
2. The egrep allows extended regular expressions. The $ at the end means that the filename has to end in, example, tif. Hence, foo.tif.bar will not be considered as a match.
3. The pipes are an OR to match any of the patterns.

Comment: Given that GNU find includes a lot of non-standard features and there are plenty of systems which do not use GNU utilities, I would err on the side of caution and avoid extensions which are easily avoided (such as not specifying `.`). This is also a much less efficient solution than Stephen's.

Comment: this will fail if there are any files whose names contain newlines. And it also fails to find files with mixed cases like `.Tif`, `.tiFF`...

Comment: @phulcv Correct. However, this was not part of the question,  There was no need to downvote :)
 Will, I added a disclaimer that it would work only for simple cases (he is a newbie and I was trying to avoid advanced usage).